# Linux 64 bit only recognizing 3gb of RAM out of 6

Tags: linux-mint, 64bit, ram

I'm running Linux Mint 17.1 (cinnamon) on a Dell XPS 630i core 2 quad. I recently upgraded to 6GB of RAM only to realize that Mint is only recognizing 3GB. I confirmed that the system is indeed 64 bit and upgraded the kernel to latest stable 3.19 64 bit. The BIOS is recognizing all 6GB. I updated the BIOS simply because it's an older system and there was an update available. I have been unable to resolve this issue and am quickly running out of ideas.

[pastebin - dmidecode](http://pastebin.com/cRYcHcfW)

Comment: Have you tried booting with a different distribution, a live CD, or even Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I did try to use the live CD and realized then what the problem was. For some reason when I try to boot using the live CD it never actually boots. When the Grub loader starts the computer goes into an infinite reboot loop. I had to change the boot parameters (way back when) to 'mem=3000M' and that is why it only recognized 3gb. I've since changed (grub.cfg) it to 'mem=MEMORY_LIMIT' and I seem to be back on track. Thanks for your reply!